# xelatex vs. xelatexmk compilation – what’s the difference?

Tags: xetex, compiling, latexmk

I'm using TeX Live 2012 in a Windows environment.

I used to compile with `xelatexmk`, which isn't included in TeX Live's "Processing tools". When I wanted to switch from LaTeX to XeLaTeX, I read somewhere that I had to compile with `xelatexmk`, and it gave instructions for its configuration.

My `xelatexmk` configuration looks like this:

[image]

Then I recently switched to TeX Live's built-in `XeLaTeX` compiler, because I noticed it was faster and always gave the same result. That configuration looks like this:

[image]

But I've noticed a difference when I draw arrows with `TikZ`. Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (finisharrow) {a}; & \tikz[baseline, remember picture] \node[inner sep = 0pt, anchor = base] (startarrow) {c};
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shorten <=.1ex, shorten >=.1ex]
        \draw [semithick, ->] (startarrow) -- (finisharrow);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile with `xelatexmk`, it gives me this:

[image]

When I compile with `XeLaTeX`, on the other hand, it gives me this:

[image]

I need to compile with `XeLaTeX` a second time to get the proper outcome:

[image]

I'm sure there's a perfectly good reason why `XeLaTeX` behaves this way, but for novice users like me, it resulted in a lot of frustration, since I couldn't figure out why my arrows didn't turn out the way they used to before (when I used `xelatexmk`).

Could this perhaps be a reason why `XeLaTeX` in the future versions of TeX Live should do two compiling iterations, or why `xelatexmk` should be included? Again, I need to stress that this is from the perspective of a novice user, who generally expects (or hopes) that their `.tex` document compiles easily by using some default built-in compiler.

Comment: When you use `remember picture`, there's need of a second run of LaTeX (whichever variant), because during the first a note is kept for the location of the picture; it's similar to the `\label`-`\ref` system. A new run in necessary whenever the picture is modified or its position in the page changes.

Comment: I've understood now, that this is precisely why ``latexmk`` was made (to perform as many runs as necessary). Maybe I should close my question as being too localized.

Comment: @Sverre I disagree, why should this be *too localized*? Just because you understand now doesn’t mean it’s an illegitimate question that somebody might have as well. Voting to reopen. (After taking the liberty to generalize the question slightly.)

Comment: I see what you mean after having reworded the question. I guess my thought was that it now boils down to whether or not TeX Live should include ``latexmk`` among its included compiling tools (which I think it should). And my initial question here was, in a way, too localized to address that properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xelatex` command runs XeLaTeX exactly once: it does one typesetting run and produces a PDF. In contrast, `xelatexmk` runs XeLaTeX and other tools one or more times, using a script to (try to) determine what runs are required. Once you go beyond a 'trivial' document, introducing cross-references or similar then at least two XeLaTeX runs are required to 'completely' compile a document (here we have a 'label' of sorts in terms of position in the output). On the other hand, scripts don't always get things right, and resolving all links, *etc.* is normally only essential for the final 'production' PDF. As such, many people are happy not to use a script and to do the necessarily additional runs by hand, which means that intermediate runs are faster. Others are happier with a script doing this 'back end' stuff for them.